# Getting wrong Base64 for image in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, base64

I want to generate Base64 string for a specific image.
for that I've wrote below code

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgProfile.image!)!
var imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
```

and I'm getting [this](http://dpaste.com/1DNSD2P) output string as Base64 which is not decoded (i.e. wrong).

but when I'm generating Base64 from [here](http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image), I'm getting [this](http://dpaste.com/1HNM669) output string, which is successfully decoded and getting the image back (i.e. correct)

Please help me to find the issue.
Thanks in advance

I've already visited following threads.
1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47610733/3110026 
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46309421/3110026

Comment: Tried with `data.base64EncodedString()` only not with options?

Comment: The string is properly encoded. You are adding CRLF (`\n\r`) after each 64 characters with the options you passed. What do you expect? To decode the string ignoring the new lines you have to pass `.ignoreUnknownCharacters`.

Comment: @vadian I'm not adding any CRLF characters. as you can see there is "Pwq5Uhn1T836" string before AAAAA at the end of string on original, but there is no like that string in my generated string

Comment: You do add CRLF characters. The option `lineLength64Characters` does that. The text in your [link](http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image) contains a lot of them. Please see my answer.

Comment: @TheTiger thank you for help. got original image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is properly encoded. You are adding CRLF (`\n\r`) after each 64 characters with the options you passed.

The simplest solution is to pass **no options**

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgProfile.image!)!
let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

Or decode the data with options `ignoreUnknownCharacters`

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgProfile.image!)!
let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
...
if let data = Data(base64Encoded: imageStr, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional,
I was getting the same problem, but for me \r\n was not the issue, when i get the base64 string from server there were blank spaces between some characters and after comparing it with correct Base64 string what i found is that i have to add "+" sign in blank spaces. When I did that...Bingooooo......
"yourBase64String" can contain \r\n..

```
if let cleanImageString =  yourBase64String.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+") {
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: cleanImageString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
            yourImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: yourBase64String.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "") fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

try below UIImage extension:

```
extension UIImage {



    /// Encoded Base64 String of the image
    var base64: String? {
        guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0) as NSData? else {
            print("Error occured while encoding image to base64. In \(self), \(#function)")
            return nil
        }
        return imageData.base64EncodedString()
    }


}
```

Comment: Is anything different than converting from png to jpeg? Cause I've already tried that

Comment: yup, based on image type pong or jpg

Comment: Answers are more helpful if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of dumping code only.